# How to pass and display the js variable value into html page?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file (which will start when invoked from my application when the user selects an item in my application).
In that file I have a variable and am storing a large, dynamic string (based on the user selection) in that variable.

Now I want to open a new page from the Javascript and display the value stored in the string variable in that page.

How do I pass the variable value and display it in that page?

I can use window.open() to open a new window.

Comment: Stick a URL parameter into your `window.open()` call, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Step1

Open the new window like below

```
newWindow = window.open('newpage.html',/* other parameters */);
```

Step2

write a function in the new window

```
function passValue(val){
// do stuff
}
```

Step3

once the window is open , call the function to pass the value like below

```
newWindow.passValue('your value')
```

You are done..!!

Cheers